# How are objects returned by methods initialized?

Tags: objective-c

Let me consider following piece of code:

```
Person *peter = [people chooseRandomPerson];
```

where "people" is class instance, which was already initialised, and "chooseRandomPerson" is method which returns object of "Person" type. I wonder if it's the same as following:

```
Person *peter = [[Person alloc] init];
peter = [people chooseRandomPerson];
```

If not, what is the difference. If not, can I use such a substitution anytime? I am sorry, if the question is elementary, but I wasn't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second creates an object, puts it into the variable `peter`, and then immediately discards it* to store the return value of `chooseRandomPerson`.

The variable `peter` is a **place to put a thing**; the object is **the thing you get back** from the `alloc`/`init` or the `chooseRandomPerson`. You don't need to create a thing in order to have a place to put it; the declaration `Person *peter;` creates the place -- the variable -- by itself.

---

<sub>*If you weren't using [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting), this would be a leak, but if you're asking this you'd better be using ARC.</sub>

Comment: The variable `peter` is a place to put *the address* of the thing.  `alloc` creates the place.

Comment: You're right, of course, @nhgrif, but I think that pointers are still a lesson or two down the road.

Comment: And the *thing* returned from the method at some point, somewhere, went through the `alloc] init]` process somewhere, so we're not really skipping that... we just don't see it here.

Comment: Not trying to say this answer is wrong, just a couple of points of possible further clarification (and hopefully not confusion) for the Questioner.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233246/642706) is correct. But your question is not entirely clear.

In your question, you never define what is "people". You say "class instance" by which you presumably meant "object". But an object/instance of what class? Using the plural word "people" suggests a collection of objects. You should clarify this in your question.

## Object Creating Sibling Objects

If you are asking *"Can an object return a new instance of its own class?"*, the answer is "Yes". In your example, "peter" a Person object can produce a new Person object, "Sally".

However, an object creating sibling objects (new objects of the same class) is somewhat unusual in my experience. More common would be a using the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to produce instances.

There is one common use of an object creating sibling objects: [Immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Instead of changing one field of data in a DateTime object, an entirely new object is created with most of its data based on the original.