# How to get the data from a row in an NSArray using only part of the row to search

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Lets say i have an array filled with several rows

```
dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2012-05-01||Blue", @"2012-05-02||Red", @"2012-05-03||Green", @"2012-05-04||Orange", @"2012-05-05||Yellow", @"2012-05-06||Purple", @"2012-05-07||Silver", nil];
```

and then I have a date to search by ***2012-05-01***

How do i search for an object by only part of it without doing a big for( loop because this array will theoretically hold a few thousand cells.

EDIT:

if necessary how do i load the data into an NSDictionary? (i've never used them)

I know i can get the data like so

```
for(NSString *row in dates) {
NSString *date = [[row componentsSeperatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *color = [[row componentsSeperatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're using the proper class for your needs. You should probably be using an NSDictionary and use the date as key.

Comment: Yeah, im agreeing with you, but my problem is the whole app is integrated into these strings. I suppose if i could load all of those object into an NSDictionary searching would be much easier.

Comment: That's another red flag right there: Storing dates as strings!

Comment: A "row" in an NSArray is a pointer to an object.  You can't search for part of a pointer.

Comment: (If you're afraid of using an NSDictionary then you shouldn't be programming in Objective-C at all.)

Comment: well it'll be swift soon lol. All jokes aside, it's not that i'm afraid its that i've never looked into it, which i am now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *colorsAndDates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

for(NSString *row in dates) {
    NSString *dateString = [[row componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSString *color = [[row componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:1];

    [colorsAndDates setObject:color forKey:date];
}
```

If I am correct, this will format it into an `NSDictionary`, and then I can grab the color using:

```
NSString *dateToFind = @"2012-05-01";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateToFind];
NSString *theColor = [colorsAndDates objectForKey:date];
```

Knowing this, I will have to go back and make it all revolve around `NSDictionary` instead of the strings they're in.

Comment: (Note: you don't need to (and shouldn't) create an `NSDate` before getting one from the date formatter. It's just thrown away. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24233246/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do other than looping through the array:

1) Use a sorted array.  Even if you need to keep the data in the initial order, you can make a sorted copy of it.  Then you can do a binary search (if there are n items, check the n/2 item, if it's less than your date and repeat the process with only the data from n/2 to n, or if it's greater, then repeat with the data from 0 to n/2.  Sort once, find many.

2) Create a dictionary on the fly using the data.  You can use the the 10 character prefix of the data as the key.  You'll have to maintain the dictionary along with the array, so this may not be practicable if you have a lot of changes. Create dictionary once, find many. (Note: despite the answers you've gotten, a dictionary may not be the best solution, particularly if you don't have unique keys (i.e. more than one record with the same date).

3) Forget the arrays and store your data in sqlite, and write a sql statement to get it.  Most useful if you have a whole lot of data. You can use sqlite to build a primary key if you have duplicate dates in your data.

Comment: If you have hash collisions, hanging a list off of each key is still likely to be better than one huge list.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes but that requires some extra programming to make work correctly. sqlite will let him store huge amounts of data, handle duplicates if he uses a sequenced primary key, and find his data quickly and accurately.  He just has to write a little SQL for it.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion; my comment was only directed at the note ending item 2, not your suggestion to use SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dateDictionary = @{
                                 @"2012-05-01" : @"Blue",
                                 @"2012-05-02" : @"Red",
                                 @"2012-05-03" : @"Green",
                                 @"2012-05-04" : @"Orange",
                                 @"2012-05-05" : @"Yellow",
                                 @"2012-05-06" : @"Purple",
                                 @"2012-05-07" : @"Silver"
                                 };

NSString *date = @"2012-05-01";
NSString *dateColor = dateDictionary[date];
```

Using the example you gave (looping through the array to create a dictionary):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dateDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(NSString *row in dates) {
    NSString *date = [[row componentsSeperatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *color = [[row componentsSeperatedByString:@"||"] objectAtIndex:1];

    dateDictionary[date] = color;
}

NSString *date = @"2012-05-01";
NSString *dateColor = dateDictionary[date];
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote an answer please at least leave a comment explaining why.  To my knowledge this directly answered the question, "how do i load the data into an NSDictionary? (i've never used them)".